# Postfix - How to route outbound mail from multiple local Postfix servers

Tags: postfix

There are plenty of articles concerning postfix servers and multiple domains, relays and smarthost however they don't seem to address the architecture I have.

I have built a small network consisting of 3 Debian Jessie servers for the sake of this question Servers A, B & C, they are all on a local network with 192.168.x.x IP addresses.

Server A is the only web facing server and hosts web and email services. Email is configured to relay through an external (gmail) server - until I move to a proper domain and is stable and working fine for both incoming/outgoing email originated on Server A.

Servers B & C run other services such as database and one of them (server C) is running Nagios host/service monitoring.

My ultimate goal is to have Nagios mail out service update notifications and to do this it will need to send emails via Server A as that is the only internet facing server.

My assumption is that I will need to have postfix running on Server C and somehow configure it to send mail via Server A, likewise for Server A to accept mail from Server C for forwarding.

Is my assumption correct and if show how do I configure the servers to do this?

If my assumption is incorrect, what is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `relayhost` parameter in the `main.cf` file:

[Relayhost documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relayhost)

Add on the server C to the /etc/postfix/main.cf this line:

```
relayhost = IP.address.of.A
```

Then you have to restart `postfix` service.

Answer (score 0):

A mail exchange is a router, there is no need to reinvent the wheel. Use a single mail router and configure the applications to use it, you don't need to install a new mail server for every appliance, this would be like installing a new domain controller because you application needs users